# Clearing the List of a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview

I dont have a custom list, I extend with a list fragment. But I am clearly unable to clear the list, I have tried some few possibilities but was unable

```
    ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String item: arr) {
        if (item.contains(".mp3"))

            places.add(item);
    }


    adapter1= new Adapter1(p.getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, places);

    adapter1.setNotifyOnChange(true);


    setListAdapter(adapter1);
```

arr is just an array of string.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your question is not related to your code..

Comment: I have written the code to add items, I asked a question to clear the items which is in it

Answer (score 2):

To clear your list you can simply empty your places list and notify the adapter.

```
places.clear();
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```